# How to round down a Python Decimal to 1 decimal places?

Tags: python, decimal

I write a fuction to round down the values, but I have a trouble when I round down 65.80. It gives me 65.7, not 65.8.

This is my code:

```
def quantize_down(x):
    return float(Decimal(x).quantize(Decimal('.1'), rounding='ROUND_DOWN'))

print("quantize_down(65.8)")
print("Result", quantize_down(65.8))
print('-------------')
print("quantize_down(65.80):")
print("Result:", quantize_down(65.80))
print('-------------')
print("quantize_down(65.81)")
print("Result", quantize_down(65.81))
print('-------------')
print("quantize_down(65.87)")
print("Result", quantize_floor(65.87))
print('-------------')
```

Then I get this:

```
quantize_down(65.8)
Result 65.7
-------------
quantize_down(65.80):
Result: 65.7
-------------
quantize_down(65.81)
Result 65.8
-------------
quantize_down(65.87)
Result 65.8
-------------
```

But I want this:

```
quantize_down(65.8)
Result 65.8
-------------
quantize_down(65.80):
Result: 65.8
-------------
quantize_down(65.81)
Result 65.8
-------------
quantize_down(65.87)
Result 65.8
-------------
```

What can i do to get that?

Comment: It's probably because you're passing and returning `float` values.  Try passing in strings and removing the `float()` around your result.

Comment: Passing a string, It works. Thanks